# Break down the statements rather than using comma

Tags: swift

I have the following implementation, but I need break down the statements do not combine them using `,`. What is the best approach to refactor the existing code?

```
do {
   let school = try schoolManager.currentSchool(), schoolName = school.name
   return schoolName
} catch {
   return nil
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don’t really do anything with `school` other than grabbing its `name`, you might just do:

```
do {
   return try schoolManager.currentSchool().name
} catch {
   return nil
}
```

Or, even even more concise, since you’re not doing anything with the error thrown by `try`, you can instead use `try?` and optional chaining, e.g.:

```
let school = try? schoolManager.currentSchool()
return school?.name
```

Or

```
return (try? schoolManager.currentSchool())?.name
```

Comment: or propagate the error making the method throw (usually the best option IMO)

Comment: Or it begs the question whether `currentSchool` throws meaningful errors at all, or whether perhaps it should just return an optional and not throw errors at all. But this answer was attempting to address the specific issue on how to simplify the syntax raised in the question.